# Where has windows working sets gone in Eclipse 3.4

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.4

Where can I find the option to switch between the Windows Working Set in Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede)?  In the previous version it was under then Window menu, but it appears to have moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have it under 'Windows' menu.

Windows/Working Sets/[your different working sets]

You select the different working sets you want to be displayed in the package explorer. So it is not exactly a "switch" anymore, rather a filter.

Comment: Correct, although I had to customize the perspective to show it (window > customize perspective)

Answer (score 4):

In the package explorer you will see a small triangle in the top right of the menu bar.

Click on this will pop up a menu.

You can then select "Top Level Elements" and switch between "Projects" and "Working Sets"

Answer (score 1):

I neglected to read the slashnick's comment:

Correct, although I had to customize the perspective to show it (window > customize perspective) – slashnick (Oct 28 at 9:26)

Window > customize perspective
commands tab.
check window working set in available command groups section